# How do i find out which Windows do i need?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-activation, serial

I had to reinstall my laptop, and "luckily" my recovery disk is broken...
My laptop is too old to get help from the manufacturer or the seller, BUT i have the Windows serial key at the bottom of the laptop.
I downloaded Win7 Pro, wanted to activate and turned out the key is not for this version. How do i find out which one i have to get (before i download and install every version)?

Comment: The COA sticker indicates which version and edition the license key is valid for.  If the license key is printed on the sticker, then you have this information, it sounds like your license key wasn't for Windows 7 Professional but for a different edition of Windows 7.

Comment: I think sometimes last time I checked, like 15 years ago and perhaps still today,  for dell machines, the dell windows key won't work for a regular windows installation disk.  You might be able to get a dell windows disk or recovery disk off ebay in that situation.  And still use the key on your laptop sticker.    It may be the same applies if it were HP

Answer (score 0):

Most All OEM COA stickers for Windows 7 have the version printed on them.

Install the version on the sticker and use the key from that sticker.

[Click to see sticker](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fis2.ecplaza.com%2Fecplaza2%2Fproducts%2F4%2F45%2F45f%2F1005110799%2Fwindows-product-key.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fproductkey.en.ecplaza.net%2Fproducts%2Fwindows-product-key-sticker-win-10_4048433&docid=JZXqnRc_R_eewM&tbnid=JLGQw3v0D-3BaM%3A&vet=12ahUKEwjl-sjP1NvcAhUFZKwKHcAFA5s4rAIQMygGMAZ6BAgBEAc..i&w=3192&h=1116&bih=1352&biw=1718&q=windows%20coa&ved=2ahUKEwjl-sjP1NvcAhUFZKwKHcAFA5s4rAIQMygGMAZ6BAgBEAc&iact=mrc&uact=8)

An Example:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, there is trouble embedding images today, thanks for trying.